# How to do a `float: left` with no wrapping?

Tags: css, css-position, css-float

I have a container `box1` that has a certain width (which might change depending on its content). That box contains `box2` which has a fixed width (it could be an icon). Next to `box2`, I have `box3` with  some text. I want the text to use all the space available to the right of `box2`. With the HTML pasted below, you get:

[image: Short text]

So far so good. If the text gets longer, it doesn't wrap around `box2` (which is what I want), however, it doesn't make `box1` grow, which is my problem. You'll tell me "hey, if you made `box3` a `position: absolute`, how could you expect it to make `box1` grow?". Well, I don't but then, how can I get `box3` to show next to `box2`, use all the horizontal space available, and make `box1` grow if necessary? (Do I need to say that I'd like this work on IE6 onward, and to avoid using a table?)

[image: Long text]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            #box1 { position: relative }
            #box3 { position: absolute; left: 2.5em; right: .5em; top: .5em }

            /* Styling */
            #box1 { background: #ddd; padding: 1em 0.5em; width: 20em }
            #box2 { background: #999; padding: .5em; }
            #box3 { background: #bbb; padding: .5em; }
            body  { font-family: sans-serif }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box1">
            <span id="box2">2</span>
            <span id="box3">3</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you do not wish for the result to look like the second illustration and would instead like for box1 to expand downwards to enclose box2 and box3?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need box 3 to be a block level element, so use `display:block` and then toss in an `overflow:hidden` in conjunction with `float`-ing box 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            #box1 {  }
            #box2 { float:left; }
            #box3 { display:block;overflow:hidden; }

            /* Styling */
            #box1 { background: #ddd; padding: 1em 0.5em; width: 20em }
            #box2 { background: #999; padding: .5em; }
            #box3 { background: #bbb; padding: .5em; }
            body  { font-family: sans-serif }

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <title>How to do a `float: left` with no wrapping?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box1">
            <span id="box2">2</span>
            <span id="box3">3<br />3<br />3<br />3<br />3<br />3<br />3<br />3<br />3<br />3<br />3<br />3<br /></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Amazing all the things `overflow:hidden` can do :D

Comment: this works great, thank you! I documented this solution in more details here (I was interested in knowing why the `overflow: hidden` has that effect), and also present another solution there, which uses a `margin-left`:
http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/browser#TOC-Prevent-a-box-from-extending-below-

Comment: @avernet's link doesn't point to the relevant section. Here's the correct link http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/browser#TOC-Prevent-a-box-from-extending-below-a-float

Comment: `overflow:hidden` indeed works very well in many cases, including this one. But a solution that works more consistently across the board is the clearfix mentioned in @hesselbom's answer. For a more full-fledged grid solution that's still very flexible (i.e. not limited to a 12-column layout), see http://csswizardry.com/2013/02/responsive-grid-systems-a-solution/. See also the frameworks http://purecss.io/ and http://materializecss.com/.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. Two common ones is either to have an empty element right after with a `clear: both` like so (inline css just for demo):

```
<span class="box1">...</span>
<br style="clear:both"/>
```

Another way is to use `overflow: hidden` like so:

```
<span class="box1" style="overflow: hidden">...</span>
```

However, there are problems with both of these solutions. With the first one you add unnecessary and ugly markup. And with the second if you want something to be positioned outside of your box (like a `position: absolute`) it won't be visible.

A more common, modern solution is to use the `::after` pseudo-element and clear that like so:

```
.box1::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I'd recommend the following:

```
#box1
{
    position: relative; /* or some other positioned value */
}

#box2
{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#box3
{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

If `#box2` is of a fixed size, you can simply use a margin for `#box3` to prevent its overlapping of `#box2`, and since it's not positioned, `#box1` will grow as `#box3` grows.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to chime in, but this isn't working for me. Here is the HTML with the styling you suggest: http://goo.gl/dNWp4. @Richard's suggestion (http://goo.gl/3H96P) works for me, so unless you're particularly interested in this, no need to worry about it.

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that they were spans and not divs.  If a `display: block` is used on them, it should work better.

Comment: I see, and got it to work using a `display: block`. You use a combination of `position: absolute` on box 2 and `margin-left` on box 3 so it doesn't overlap box 2. I also found a very similar solution using a `float: left` on box 2 instead of the `position: absolute`. See "solution 2" in this section:
http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/browser#TOC-Prevent-a-box-from-extending-below-