# Float ::before content without wrapping

Tags: html, css

Given the following markup:

```
<blockquote>This is a quote, and it's probably going to 
flow over multiple lines</blockquote>
```

Is it possible, using only CSS, to add an image to the left and give the entire quote a margin so that it does not wrap around the image.

The requirements are similar to [`How to do a 'float: left' with no wrapping?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710417/how-to-do-a-float-left-with-no-wrapping), except that I'd like to do it entirely via CSS (it's CMS-generated content, so adding additional elements proves problematic).

Here's what I have so far ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg2qh/1/)):

```
blockquote::before {
    content: "";
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #999;
}
```

Which does everything apart from avoid wrapping.

**Edit:** I'm using `::before` rather than simply specifying padding+background-image because the background image I want to use is sprited and doing so would allow other images in the sprite to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `float: left` make the `<blockquote>` relatively positioned and the `:before` absolutely positioned.  `right: 100%` rule will always position the `:before` to the left of the `<blockquote>`.  It will need a margin, of course.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/mg2qh/3/

Answer (score 2):

I could be completely wrong, but if I understand your question correctly you're way overcomplicating this, and [this would be what you ask](http://jsfiddle.net/mg2qh/4/). Just set a padding on the `blockquote` and use a background...?

If the background is sprited and as such needs a fixed size, [use absolute positioning like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/FAUaJ/1/).

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed this point for my original post: the background image I want to use is actually sprited, which complicates simply using it as a background image to the entire element.

Comment: [Updated fiddle here based on that extra requirement, without ugly floats where you definitely shouldn't be using them](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/FAUaJ/1/).